# Window Order in a Single App When Clicked From Task bar in GNOME

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, launcher

One of the things I'm finding hard to get used to in the switch from Unity to GNOME is the fact that when I click on the launcher to switch to app where I have multiple windows open, the order changes based on which window was on top most recently. For example, I like to keep a Chrome window for the several different Slack workspaces I'm in, then a separate window for gmail, calendar, drive, and other basic utilities, and then browse/work in a third and fourth window.

I used to open the slack first, utilities second, then my 'working' windows. That would let me just automatically click chrome then drop to the bottom window to get to my slack window. In GNOME the order of the windows change depending on their actual layer on the desktop. I thought I'd get used to it after a few weeks, but it's taking me longer than expected. Is there a way to change this behavior to have a set order? I know that it worked that way in Unity but I can't remember if I had to make a change there or if that was just default behavior.

I hope I'm explaining this well enough - if it doesn't make sense I can take some screenshots.